# Tracking changes in data with no primary key

Tags: database, database-design, primary-key

I am writing an application that uses [CC-CEDICT](http://cc-cedict.org/wiki/), a CC licensed Chinese-English dictionary.

The dictionary is available only as a [zipped text file (4MB)](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/export/cedict/cedict_1_0_ts_utf-8_mdbg.zip) with entries in the following format:

```
Traditional Simplified [pin1 yin1] /English equivalent 1/equivalent 2/
```

This is sample data:

```
是 是 [shi4] /is/are/am/yes/to be/
昰 是 [shi4] /variant of 是[shi4]/used in given names/
時 时 [Shi2] /surname Shi/
時 时 [shi2] /o'clock/time/when/hour/season/period/
```

I chose those lines deliberately to illustrate my problem.  The data has no descernable key by which an individual word can be identified.

The English definitions can change, and do as the dictionary is constantly updated, but suppose in one update the two definitions of 時 时 change, so the next download contains the lines:

```
時 时 [Shi2] /last name Shi/
時 时 [shi2] /o'clock/time period/when/hour/season/
```

How am I to tell which records have been updated? This is really noticeable when the translation is a single word that changes completely.

I am after a strategy as to how I can key this dictionary. So far my best idea is to take (Simplified, Traditional) as the key, and treat the duplicates as a special case - in their own table perhaps??

Comment: You can't - if you want to track changes - you **must have** a primary key. Any real data table ought to have a primary key anyway....

Answer (score 1):

The issue is one of perspective.

You say that your records have no key, but in fact the ***whole record* is the key** - assuming you have no identical duplicate records.

Therefore there are **no *updates*** only **inserts** and **deletes**.

You can track which records are deleted and which are inserted in order to highlight changes in your dictionary.

---

If you *really* want to treat definition replacements as updates, then you're going to have to come up with a scheme that (a) creates a unique key for records and (b) allows you to recognize when an new definition list should be considered a modification of an existing definition list.

Part (a) is easy, add your own surrogate key.  This could be unique across all definitions, or just across combinations of (Simplified, Traditional).

Part (b) is harder.  At what point do you say "surname Shi" is related to "last name Shi"?  I suggest coming up with some kind of text comparison function that yields a numeric score.  Pick a threshold for this score at which you call it an update instead of a delete and insert.  This will be arbitrary, but you might find that two people could disagree over what is an update and what isn't from one case to another anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but may give some ideas for you (or others).

How about modeling this as a hierarchy, Word->Meaning->Translation.
Compute a hash of the translation, sum the hash value of all translations and store that in the corresponding "meaning" record, then sum the hash values of all meanings and store that in the Word record. (Yes, this is denormalized).

You would have to recompute all the hash values for all records in the file every time. Then you could simply compare the currently stored hash value for a "word" with the hash value that you just computed. If they are different, something has changed. Either there was a new meaning, or a new translation or a translation was removed, etcetera. You could then either remove the word entirely (cascaded) and re-insert the new "sub tree". If you want to complicate things you could also descend into the hierarchy and try to detect exactly what changed.